# Need help visualising transverse waves

Tags: waves

From studying waves I find that I can visualise longitudinal waves where the wave propagates in the direction of the displacement. However I don't understand what causes the propagation perpendicular to the displacement in transverse waves. How is a perpendicular displacement caused in adjacent particles?

Comment: It is the Energy which propagates in the perpendicular direction. e.g. waves on a string, the adjacent particles pick the energy from those before them.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_wave has an animation

Comment: Why does the energy propagate in a direction perpendicular to the motion and why does the energy cause perpendicular motion in subsequent particles?

Answer (score 2):

[This transverse plane wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_wave)  is illustrated here

[image: transverse wave]

If we go to a medium, the "points " will be the molecules which are adjacent. An organized impulse is set up as a function of time, pulling down the one on the right and transferring an  impulse delta(p) in the longitudinal direction  and then the next molecule pulls up and passes the impulse.

Answer (score 1):

A longitudinal wave is what you get when you stretch and compress a slinky or spring.  The slinky can stay inside the cylinder, but you can see it compressing and expanding.  Sound is longitudinal.

A transverse wave is what you get when you wave the end of a piece of string up and down.  The bits go up and down, but the waveform travels along the string.  Light is transverse, as are ocean waves.